# How do I delete a user from an azure B2C Active Directory programatically with C#

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I have created a [B2C(Preview)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory-b2c/) Azure Active Directory to allow people to sign up to a website. The website works fine but I now require the ability to delete a user who has signed up from the active directory. How do I do this through C# code?

I have found answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426035/delete-user-in-active-directory-using-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562160/delete-an-user-in-active-directory-via-c-sharp) however it feels like I'm missing something fundamental because I have no idea what LDAP is or where I am meant to get that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Azure AD Graph API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart/), it is providing the access to the Azure AD directory.

Sample is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/9e123189250f72197a6628ab9ecdc9c4a66d1626/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs).

I am not completely sure (i made a research right now), but it looks like the Azure AD does not support LDAP yet. Tutorials you have found are local AD-related, but Azure AD is not a complete replacement for that. You can read about AD (highly recommended! very interesting) [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-identity/).

Comment: I've used that and made some progress. With help from [this](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory) I've managed to set it up and I can at least query the Active Directory and get a list of the users. Once I have a user there is a user.DeleteAsync() method however when I call it I get an error that I have insufficient privileges, not sure why because I have enabled all permissions possible for the application.

Comment: The error is simply "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.", thrown during user.DeleteAsync(). I have enabled literally every permission on the azure portal though...

Comment: What are the rights exactly? AFAIK, you should be Company Admin to make that not only read/write/etc. There are some discussiong on the GitHub, see if the proposed answers will work for you? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/5

Comment: I looked at those and used powershell to set the application to be a "Company Administrator" as it suggested and I can finally delete a user! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Mark the question answered then, please.

Comment: If you delete users with an app registration (in example your own api in front of the graph), you can give the service principal of your app registration the "User Administrator" role to delete users.